# Xamarin forms - Change grid row visibility dynamically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid, visibility

I want to change a specific row visibility inside of a grid named "myGrid" given an index dynamically.
I thought first to get the specific row that I want use:

```
var row = Grid.GetRow(myGrid.Children[index]);
```

and then , to change the IsVisible attribute of 'row' like this:

```
row.IsVisible = false;
```

Unfortunately the second line of code Isn't legal...

I don't want to bind 'IsVisible' attribute of each row. It seem to me unnecessary work.

Any suggestion to solving this issue will be appreciate!!

Comment: SO what you want is to hide the whole row?

Comment: Yes, given an index I want to hide the whole row of that index.

Comment: Problem is that GetRow actually returns the row index for the View you passed as parameter. Above code seems to work only if you have one child per row, in that case you should be able to do myGrid.Children[index].IsVisible = false; right?

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to bind the IsVisible property of each control in the row to a single property in your view model. Then all you have to do is change the value of your view model property to `false` and the whole row will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:** 
 `GetRow` returns an int value.So you can't set the property like `IsVisible`

**Solution:**

You can set the rowHeight as `0` if you want to hide the specific row.

```
 var row = myGrid.RowDefinitions[index];
 row.Height = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

As others said, you are trying to change the visibility of an index (That is definitely wrong).

You cannot get the row of a Grid and set its visibility. Instead, you should set the visibility of the view inside the row.

But you should note that by doing so you may see an empty space inside the Grid if you have specified a fixed height or even star sizing for that row height.

It is better to set row height to **Auto**. By doing this, when the view inside that row is invisible, the height of the row decreases to 0.